# Querying large dataset from Snowflake with Python/psycopg2

Tags: python, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, psycopg2

We have large simple dataset with two columns: tension. and time and a foreign key device_id stored in Snowflake. We query like

```
def get_waveform(self, device_id):
    sql = """
         select tension, time from waveform 
         where device_id = %s;
     """

    with self.conn.cursor() as cursor:
        # This will take 12 minutes for one waveform.

        results = cursor.execute(sql, (device_id,))
        waveform = results.fetchall()
        return waveform;
```

Each device has exactly 50 mln rows. Querying this amount of data in Snowflake takes about 15 seconds on 1000Mbs network. However doing it from Python/psycopg2 is unusably long - about 12 minutes when we use fetchall. Splitting the query into smaller chunks of 1 mln each and calling fetchmany(1000000) makes things little worse about 15 minutes for all 50 queries.

My guess is the most of the time is spent parsing the query results on the client and creating the result array. Is there a workaround besides dumping Python and rewriting everything in one of the compiled languages ?

Comment: Two options 1) [Server side cursor](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#server-side-cursors) 2) [Copy](https://www.psycopg.org/docs/usage.html#using-copy-to-and-copy-from)

Comment: @Parfait there is no such thing as local Snowflake. And of course it is not network. See the question.

Answer (score 0):

I looked into the implementation of fetchall and it is simply a iteration of fetchone. Quite disappointing.
I tried to get Pandas frame

```
waveform = results.fetch_pandas_all()
```

and that implementation is much more optimal. I got the expected 12 seconds instead of 15 minutes.